# Python (Pandas) how to retrive number value from csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I apologise for the nooby question, however after reading the documentation I still can't read double/int data in from my csv program, I think it's a simple syntactic error but could someone help me out?

setting up the data frame:

```
data_frame = pandas.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['time', 'low', 'high', 'open', 'close', 'volume'])
data_frame.set_index('time', inplace=True)
```

trying to read the data:

```
change = ((data_frame['high'][time[1]]/data_frame['low'][time[0]])-1)*100
print(str(change))
```

error log:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webcrawl.py", line 99, in <module>
    processData()
  File "webcrawl.py", line 94, in processData
    change = ((data_frame['high'][time[1]]/data_frame['low'][time[0]])-1)*100
TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Can you add the whole traceback...

Comment: @advay.umare done

Comment: add some data? `data_frame.head().values.tolist()`

Comment: I just guess bc the full code is not shown but it could be that you imported the module `time` and therefore e.g. your `time[1]` fails with this error

Comment: That might be the case..

Comment: @DAXaholic thats; exactly what happened, makes total sense !

Comment: @DAXaholic feel free to add that as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: @AdrianCoutsoftides Added the answer - nice to hear that it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the error message I guess the module `time` was imported and therefore accessing `time[1]` fails as it tries to index into the module object.